# Ajax call to an angular app returns an error 404 on existing route

Tags: angular, http, request, localhost

I working on a internationalization library for angular and I'd like to make an angular component which returns all the translations for a given language. Just to test I created the following TranslateComponent

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'trans-translate',
    templateUrl: './translate.component.html'
})
export class TranslateComponent {
    // region Public fields
    public data: string[] = ['This', 'is', 'Sparta'];
    // endregion
}
```

with the simple html template with display the data:

```
{{ data | json }}
```

The url to access to this component is http://localhost:4200/translate and if I access it from the browser evertything work well (i have the following result: [ "This", "is", "Sparta" ] displayed.
The problem is that I want to call it with HttpClient and there it does not work. I just did this simple test:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-page-test',
    templateUrl: './test-page.component.html'
})
export class TestPageComponent implements OnInit {
    // region Constructor
    public constructor(
        private readonly _HTTP: HttpClient
    ) {}
    // endregion

    // region Public methods
    public ngOnInit(): void {
        this._HTTP.get('/translate').subscribe((result: any): void => {
            console.log(result);
        });
    }
    // endregion
}
```

But all I get is an error 404 with the body:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Cannot GET /translate</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

And I can't figure out what i'm missing ? Is it a header I have to add to the request ?

For the record I'm actually using angular 7 and I start the server with the command "npm run start" which basicaly just execute tu "ng serve" command.

Comment: Have you enabled Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) on the server?

Comment: It's the same server. It's the page http://localhost:4200/test making a request to http://localhost:4200/translate so i why would it be problem ,

Comment: what does the url look like for your request. Just wondering, since usually ng serve runs on `localhost:4200` and you want to target `localhost:4000` in your request

Comment: It's just a mistake in my original post, i'm really calling port 4200

Answer (score 0):

Translate and Test are two components.
localhost:4200/translate is actually a component and shows the data.

Whereas in test page you are trying to call a service using HttpClient. It's not going to call the translate component and return you data.

Hope this is what you mean when you mentioned

> t's the page localhost:4200/test making a request to
>   localhost:4200/translate so i why would it be problem

Comment: Actually I want to call the server (the TestCompont will be used in the browser but the TranslateComponent should be executing in the back end)